# jQuery infinite carousel leaves an empty space when scrolling to the left

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, infinite

I'm using a jQuery responsive carousel to display some images and text. The carousel works perfectly when clicking on the forward (right) button (the hidden slide appears smoothly until it gets into place), but it has a weird behavior when clicking on the backward (left) button, because a blank space (as wide as the slide) appears and only after the animation is completed the slide appears suddenly.

This is my html code:

```
<div id='carousel_container'>  

  <div id='left_scroll'><img src='navleft.png' /></div>  

     <div id='carousel_inner'>

        <ul id="carousel_ul">
           <li> ....content...</li>
           <li> ....content...</li>
                   .........
        </ul>

     </div>

  <div id='right_scroll'><img src='navright.png' /></div> 

</div>
```

This is my css:

```
#carousel_container{
    display:table;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#carousel_inner {  
  float:left;   
  width:660px;   
 overflow: hidden; 
}  

#carousel_ul {  
 position:relative;  
 left:0px;  
 list-style-type: none; 
 padding: 0px;
 margin:0;
 width:9999px; /* important */ 
 padding-bottom:10px;  
}  

#carousel_ul li{  
  float: left; 
  width:210px;  
  padding:0px;     
  margin-top:10px;  
  margin-bottom:10px;  
  margin-left:5px;  
  margin-right:5px;  
 }  


 #left_scroll, #right_scroll{  
    float:left;  
  }  

 #left_scroll img, #right_scroll img{  
   cursor: pointer;  
   cursor: hand;  
  }
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

    //when user clicks the image for sliding right  
    jQuery('#right_scroll img').click(function(){  

    var item_width = jQuery('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;  

    var left_indent = parseInt(jQuery('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - 
     item_width;  

    jQuery('#carousel_ul').animate({'left' : left_indent},
     {duration:500, complete: function(){   

      jQuery('#carousel_ul li:last').after(jQuery('#carousel_ul 
      li:first'));  

      jQuery('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '0px'}); 

     }   
    });  
    });


    //when user clicks the image for sliding left  
    jQuery('#left_scroll img').click(function(){  

    var item_width = jQuery('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;  


    var left_indent = parseInt(jQuery('#carousel_ul').css('left')) + 
    item_width;  


     jQuery('#carousel_ul').animate({'left' : left_indent},
     {duration:500, complete: function(){  

     jQuery('#carousel_ul li:first').before(jQuery('#carousel_ul 
     li:last'));  

     jQuery('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '0px'}); 

    }

    });  

  });  
});
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling it to rotate the items *after* the animation completes. This is fine when going forward, because you want the animation to complete, and then the offscreen item to be pushed to the end. But when going back you need to move the last item into place at the front of the carousel (offscreen) and *then* animate. Something like:

```
//when user clicks the image for sliding left  
jQuery('#left_scroll img').click(function(){
  var item_width = jQuery('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;  

  // rotate elements
  jQuery('#carousel_ul li:first').before(jQuery('#carousel_ul li:last'));  

  // start offscreen
  jQuery('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : (-item_width)+'px'}); 

  // animate
  jQuery('#carousel_ul').animate({'left' : 0},{duration:500});
});
```